# Dask - compute(scheduler='processes') dont works well on prompt

Tags: python, dask

When I run dask on jupyter notebook using .compute(scheduler='processes') run well, but when i Run the same code on linux prompt dask start to run all my code, doing the previous phases before  the compute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution its simple, we have to put the code inside main method, something like this:

```
if __name__== '__main__':
   dd.compute(scheduler='processes')
```